Why is printf not printing value of ‘numtoo in my program?
int main()
{
   int firstnum ;

   printf("Enter First Number :-");

   scanf("%d" , &firstnum );

       int numtoo ;
              
       if((firstnum)%2 == 0) 
       {
           int firstquo ; 

           int numtoo = 1 ; 

           int test1; 
           test1 = firstnum ;

           do
           {
               firstquo = (test1)/2 ;

               numtoo ++ ;

               test1 = firstquo ;
           } while((test1)%2 == 0);
       }
       else 
       {
           numtoo = 0 ; 
       }

       printf("%d" , numtoo); 
}

What is this program?
I am making a program that calculates HCF of two user-input numbers. This is a small part of a bigger program. When I try to test this program separately I get the message Enter First Number. When I click enter I do not get the Numtoo value. Where did I go wrong?

You don't avoid downvotes just by saying that you don't want them. Format the code properly and put proper effort into asking the question and it won't be downvoted.

so, how to format it properly , i use ctrl +k ?

Copy-paste the code to the question, highlight the entire code, press ctrl-k. Don't  format individual lines separately.

have you tried adding a 'n? perhaps the printf isn't flushing?

You have to enter a number, not just "click enter" whatever that means. What number did you enter?

Aside: explore Euclid's algorithm for HCF (aka GCD). It's unclear what you are trying to do since you only enter one number, not two.

Your issue is related to variable scope. If you declare a variable in a new scope (between {}) it will be available to that scope only and sub-scopes.
You first declare numtoo in the scope of the function, then later in the scope of the if.
You should remove the second declaration in order to have numtoo be set to the computed value.

You  might replace "context" with "scope". If the author wants to read about it, that would be the usual term.
